# Is it true that $\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{a+1/m}^{b-1/m}=\int_{a}^{b}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{a+1/m}^{b-1/m}=\int_{a}^{b}
$$
as long as the integral on the right hand side exists? Or is this expression a non-trivial result? (I do not really recall if it is a definition, please let me know)

**Edit for precision**: Suppose $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and the integral $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is exists. Is it true that
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{a+1/m}^{b-1/m}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x?
$$

Comment: Yes its true. I think using the definition of an integral as a limit of reimann sums makes the proof pretty straightforward.

Comment: If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable, or Lebesgue integrable, or even Denjoy-Perron integrable, the function  $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ is continuous.  Also, for any of those integrals $\int_{a+h}^{b-h} f(t)\,dt = F(b-h)-F(a+h)$.  So obviously...

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Makes sense. I should have updated the post; what if $f$ is continuous over an open interval $(a,b)$ and the integral $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ exists, would the equality still hold?

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor What you mean by $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ exist, if $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor When $f$ is not defined in $a$ and $b$ the integral is improper and then it is calculated by the limits of the integrals $\int_{c}^{d}f(x)dx$ $c\to a$ and $d\to b$, with $a\leq c <d \leq b$. If this is the case, proving it is relatively easy.

Comment: @GreyFox Yes, this is what I meant. How would you prove it? I thought it could be used what B.S.Thomson said for the case $[c,d]$, but the problem about taking limits $c\to a^{+}$ and $d\to b^{-}$ is kinda problematic, as the antiderivative is not continuous at the endpoints of $(a,b)$.

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor Do you want a kind of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof?

Comment: @GreyFox Sure. If you have time for it, please do. Otherwise, if it's taking too much of your time, do you know a theorem that says something like my question?

Answer (score 2):

The poster has clarified enough perhaps to understand what the difficulty is.

One problem that many students have with starting to study integration past a first calculus course is that there are too many integrals to contend with:

1. **The Riemann integral.**  Integrable functions are bounded and it is always proved that $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ is continuous.
2. **The Newton integral.**  Integrable functions *have to be derivatives*, so $F'(x)=f(x)$ everywhere, $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ and of course $F$ is continuous (it is differentiable).
3. **The improper Riemann integral.**  For  $f$ to be integrable in this sense on $[a,b]$ there has to be (i) a finite set $S\subset [a,b]$, and (ii) a
   continuous function $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ so that the Riemann integral
   $F(d)-F(c) = \int_c^d f(t)\,dt$  if $[c,d]$ contains no point of the finite set $S$.
   Then define $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt =F(b)-F(a).$

*So continuity of $F$ is part of the definition.*   [Usually your text describes it with limits, but that is the same thing.]

4. **Continuous bounded functions.**   If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous just on $(a,b)$ and $f$ is bounded then $f$ is Riemann integrable, back to case #1.
5. **Continuous unbounded functions.**   If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous just on $(a,b)$ and $f$ is unbounded then it is not Riemann integrable, but
   might have an improper Riemann integral.  Usually that is defined by writing
   $\lim_{u\to a+, v\to b-} \int_u^v f(t)\,dt$ but that is exactly the same thing as saying that there is a continuous function  $F$ as in #3.
6. **Lebesgue integral.**  This can be defined as $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt =F(b)-F(a)$ if there is an absolutely continuous function $F$ with $F'=f$ almost everywhere.  But absolutely continuous functions are continuous.
7. **Denjoy-Perron integral.**  This can be defined as $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt =F(b)-F(a)$ if there is an ACG${}_*$   function $F$ with $F'=f$ almost everywhere.  But ACG${}_*$ functions are continuous.

**In short:** for all of these integrals, the indefinite integral $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$  is always continuous.  So the question here is immediate.
You can  *in every case* claim that
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \int_{a+\frac1m}^{b-\frac1m} f(t)\,dt = \int_a^b f(t)\,dt.$$
In fact if this is not true then the function is not integrable in any of these senses and you cannot write the expression $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$ anyway.

You will, however,   encounter discontinuous indefinite integrals when you study the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^b f(t)\,dg(t)$.

---

---

**Postscript.**

**Problem (related maybe):**  Does there exist a function $f:(0,1]\to\mathbb R$ that is continuous and for which the limit of the sequence
$$  \lim_{m\to\infty} \int_{\frac1m}^{1} f(t)\,dt $$
exists but for which
$$  \lim_{u\to 0+} \int_{u}^{1} f(t)\,dt $$
does not exist?  Such a function is not then integrable in the improper Riemann sense and so the integral  $  \int_{0}^{1} f(t)\,dt $ does not exist.

**Answer:** Yes.  Take $f(x) =\frac{d}{dx} \sin \frac{\pi}{x} $.  Observe
that $\int_{\frac1m}^{1} f(t)\,dt= \sin \pi - \sin m\pi = 0$
but
$$  \lim_{u\to0+} \int_{u}^{1} f(t)\,dt =  \lim_{u\to0+} \left[\sin \pi -  \sin \frac{\pi}{u}\right] $$
does not exist so $f$ is not integrable on $[0,1]$  (in the sense of the improper Riemann integral or any sense).

Answer (score 1):

Since improper integral $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$$ exist it means that fixing a point $c\in (a,b)$ (for example $c= (a+b)/2$), then the following limits exists:
$$\lim_{t\to a^{+}}\int_{t}^{c}f(x)dx\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{s\to b^{-}}\int_{c}^{s}f(x)dx,$$
and
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = \lim_{t\to a^{+}}\int_{t}^{c}f(x)dx + \lim_{s\to b^{-}}\int_{c}^{s}f(x)dx.$$

In particular, for the sequence $t_{m} = a + \frac{1}{m}\to a^{+}$ and $s_{m}= b-\frac{1}{m}\to b^{-}$ we have:
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = \lim_{t\to a^{+}}\int_{t}^{c}f(x)dx + \lim_{s\to b^{-}}\int_{c}^{s}f(x)dx.\\
\,\\
=\lim_{m\to \infty}\int_{t_{m}}^{c}f(x)dx + \lim_{m\to \infty}\int_{c}^{s_{m}}f(x)dx\\
\,\\
=\lim_{m\to \infty}\int_{t_{m}}^{c}f(x)dx + \int_{c}^{s_{m}}f(x)dx.$$

Since $[t_{m},s_{m}]\subset(a,b)$ holds for any $m$, we have that:
$$\lim_{m\to \infty}\int_{t_{m}}^{c}f(x)dx + \int_{c}^{s_{m}}f(x)dx = \lim_{m\to \infty}\int_{t_{m}}^{s_{m}}f(x)dx,$$
and grouping the equations and using the expression of $t_{m}$ and $s_{m}$, it follows that
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = \lim_{m\to \infty}\int_{a-\frac{1}{m}}^{b+\frac{1}{m}}f(x)dx.$$

I hope it is clear for you.